Under what conditions is a group homomorphism between rational linear algebraic groups always an algebraic map?
Under what conditions is a group homomorphism between rational linear algebraic groups always an algebraic map?
I know that this is true if the homomorphism is an isomorphism of unipotent groups, but can this assumption be weakened at all? For example what about a (maybe injective, maybe surjective) map between unipotent groups?
I think if the groups are not unipotent then there are group isomorphisms which are already not algebraic, so this assumption seems to be required.

There are some results mentioned here.

Maybe by a "rational linear algebraic group" you mean the set of rational points of an affine algebraic group over $\mathbb Q$.

@DietrichBurde, thank you very much. I think Corollary 3.8 (1) is as close to an answer as I could hope for!
